# A very simple puzzle: 1,1,2,1,2,2,3

Tags: number-sequence

Here's a simple puzzle,
I know that you will find.
As long as you can count,
It shouldn't take much time.

1
1
2
1
2
2
3
1
2
2
3

Find the next 4 numbers in this sequence.

Comment: Why the [wordplay] tag?

Comment: Well the "as long as you can count" was supposed to be a hint that it involved counting, as well as a very roundabout way of implying binary, but I don't remember what I was thinking when I was writing the rhyme, and that bit may have been lost when I rounded out the words.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> Represent natural numbers in binary. Count the 1's in the binary representation.
>
>
>   `Number   Binary  Number of 1's`
>
>   `1            1           1`
>
>   `2           10           1`
>
>   `3           11           2`
>
>   `4          100           1`
>
>   `5          101           2`
>
>   `6          110           2`
>
>   `7          111           3`
>
>   `8         1000           1`
>
>   `9         1001           2`
>
>   `10        1010           2`
>
>   `11        1011           3`
>
>   **`12        1100           2`**
>
>   **`13        1101           3`**
>
>   **`14        1110           3`**
>
>   **`15        1111           4`**
>
>
>   Next are **`2, 3, 3, 4`**

**Inspiration**

> Looked at where the 1's occur. They occur at indexes 1, 2, 4, 8. After that it was simple.

Comment: +1 for the Inspiration-Part - It's always nice to see how people approach problems and how they get to a solution!

Comment: @Falco Thanks! I've often encountered solutions which leave you wondering how on earth could somebody think of that. I think sharing the approach is as important as posting the solution.

Comment: The number of 1's is also known as the Population Count or Hamming Weight.

Answer (score 17):

Elements in the sequence are computed with the following recursive formula:

> $a_n = \begin{cases}0, & \text{if $n \le 0$}\\a_{\frac{n}{2}}, & \text{if $n$ is even}\\ a_{n-1}+1, & \text{if $n$ is odd} \end{cases}$

Thus, the values for $a_{12}$ to $a_{15}$ are

> $a_{12} = a_{6} = a_{3} = a_{2} + 1 = a_{1} + 1 = a_{0} + 1 + 1 = 2$
>  $a_{13} = a_{12} + 1 = 3$
>  $a_{14} = a_{7} = a_{6} + 1 = 3$
>  $a_{15} = a_{14} + 1 = 4$

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder if that's a more complicated way of expressing the pattern and if it holds true for more of the binary numbers.

Comment: @Kingrames It does indeed calculate the number of 1's in the binary representation. The operation corresponds to looking at the rightmost digit and then right-shifting (divide by two) until we come to zero.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not too much in the spirit of the riddle since it ignores the [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) tag, but here is another potential continuation of the sequence:

> Clearly the sequence is a level-order traversal of the binary tree
>  \begin{matrix}&&&(1)&&&\\&(1,2)&&&&(1,2)&\\(2,3,1,2)&&(2,3,?,?)& & (?,?,?,?)&&(?,?,?,?) \\\end{matrix}
>
>  where each node at level $n$ is a $(2^n)$-tuple $N_n=(N_{n,0},...,N_{n,2^n-1})$ which is decided by the equations
>  \begin{gather*}N_{0,0}=1\\N_{n,i}=N_{n-1,\lfloor\frac{2^n-1-i}{2}\rfloor}+i-2\lfloor \frac{i}{2}\rfloor\end{gather*} 
>  so the next elements in the sequence are
>  \begin{gather*}N_{2,2}=N_{1,\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\rfloor}+2-2\lfloor \frac{2}{2}\rfloor=N_{1,0}+0=1\\N_{2,3}=N_{1,\lfloor\frac{0}{2}\rfloor}+3-2\lfloor \frac{3}{2}\rfloor=N_{1,0}+1=2\\N_{2,0}=N_{1,\lfloor\frac{3}{2}\rfloor}+0-2\lfloor \frac{0}{2}\rfloor=N_{1,1}+0=2\\N_{2,1}=N_{1,\lfloor\frac{2}{2}\rfloor}+1-2\lfloor \frac{1}{2}\rfloor=N_{1,1}+1=3\end{gather*}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like $2, 3, 3, 4$ to me, since the first number is the head node of a binary tree. Going to the left you change nothing, but going to the right you add one. So,

- $1$ goes to $1,2$.
- $2$ goes to $2,3$ and
- $3$ goes to $3,4$

So when you get to $1,2,2,3$ this can only go to $1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4$. In the statement of the problem we see $1,2,2,3$ but we don't see the next $4$ numbers, which are the solution.

Comment: By the way, it took me about 5 seconds to see the answer, whereas a lot of puzzles seem to take hours. Must be the way your brain is wired on the day you look at the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this Question Late , Anyways i recognised a pattern
Take an iterator with initial value 1 , count upto n (initial value = 1).
While counting repeat every number < n, n times so ,

```
i=1 and n=1
1
i=1 , n=2
1
2
i=1 , n=3
1
2
2
3
i=1 , n=4
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
i=1 , n=5
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
```

So answer is 3  , 3 , 4 , 1